# How to test json rendered by a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have created a module `Error:ErrorHandler` that is included in my `ApplicationController` to handle errors.

```
module Error
  module ErrorHandler
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        rescue_from StandardError do |e|
          respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from CustomError do |e|
          respond(e.error, e.status, e.message.to_s)
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def respond(error, status, message: nil, json: Helpers::Render.json(error, status, message.instance_of?(Array) ? message : Array(message)))
      # Render the json, and define the HTTP status code
      render json: json, status: status
    end
  end
end
```

the `Helpers::Render.json` function looks like this:

```
    def self.json(_error, _status, _message)
      {
          error: _error,
          status: _status,
          message: _message
      }.as_json
    end
```

I am trying to create some rspec tests to check that if the json returned is as expected, but i am a bit confused testing modules that render json.

Which is the correct way to create tests for this case?

I know that the current implementation is simple and straightforward but it will scale in the future so I would like to create a proper test coverage.

Comment: This is a flawed approach to something that should be handled by setting `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` and creating a routes and a controller that handles rendering error pages. `rescue_from` will not catch routing errors or anything that occurs outside of the controller. https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application is an API

Comment: Does not really change anything except that you are rendering JSON.

Comment: I am not sure why this approach is flawed over my approach, see also this similar implementation https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-api-painless-error-handling-and-rendering-2/

Comment: Because that is an example of catching specific errors and what you are doing is a catch-all that should be done on a framework level.